# Internal Error 500 with nginx and PHP GeoIP Module

Tags: php, nginx, geolocation, geoip

I am trying to look up the country associated with an external IP (not the visitor) in a PHP script. I have installed the module. When I run `nginx -V`, *--with-geoip-module* appears in the list, and I have the GeoIP.dat file in */usr/share/GeoIP/* on my server. I also have the path to the GeoIP files in my nginx.conf:

```
geoip_country  /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat; # the country IP database
```

Here's the code I am using to test:

```
<?php
    echo geoip_country_code_by_name('69.84.125.113');
?>
```

This is returning the following error:

> PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function geoip_open() in /usr/share/nginx/html/geoip.php on line 7" while reading response header from upstream, client: 69.84.125.113, server: localhost, request: "GET /geoip.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "mydomain.com"

Please help, I've been struggling with this all day!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to include it first.

```
include ("include/geoip.inc");
```

Comment: I got it to work by adding that include and 
    $gi = geoip_open("GeoIP.dat",GEOIP_STANDARD);

But does that mean it's going to load this 700kb file every time the script is processed?  I am writing a tracking script that may fire several times per second, so loading a file that size with each run is really not ideal.

Comment: Yeah, I think it will have to load each time.  Maybe you can move the functions you need into a new file and include that instead...sounds tedious.